# Load MKMapView in background and create UIImage from it (iPhone & iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, mkmapview

I have a situation whereby I need a way of loading an MKMapView with several overlays. This map view shouldn't be shown onscreen, the only reason I require it to load is in order to create an image from the map for use elsewhere.

I have had a look around online but I haven't had any luck with finding a solution to the problem. Please can someone help me out?

Here is what I've tried so far (with no success)

```
// Load the map view
Logs_Map_ViewController *mapViewController = [[Map_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Map_ViewController" bundle:nil];
mapViewController.GPSCoordinatesToPlot = [someDictionary objectForKey:kGPSCoords];

// Take a picture of the map
UIImage *mapImage = [mapViewController convertMapToImage];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(mapImage)];
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
```

**NOTE:** It's really important that the app waits for the map to fully load (so that the image is created properly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` in the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol and store your image there, I would think. That should solve the problem of needing to wait until the map is loaded to store the image.

If you're seeing other issues as well, please provide more detail on those, as your question is not clear on the specific issue(s) that you're asking about.

Comment: I have tried implementing this delegate method, however it never seems to get called since I don't ever display the view containing the mapview.

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right, you're almost certainly not going to be able to get the actual map image without displaying the mapView, because that's what triggers it to go get data. In addition, and I bring this up only because the StackOverflow community will almost certainly innundate you with responses stating such if I don't, that it is probably a violation of Google's terms of service to use the MKMapView data for anything other than actually displaying a map. IANAL, and I'm not connected to Google, just mentioning it. Regardless, the MKMapView isn't really usable as a non-visible data source.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. I was not aware of this as an issue - I made the assumption that it would be ok to take a snap of the map and email it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can insert the map view underneath your view controller's view. This way, the map view itself is never seen, but since it's added to the view hierarchy, the delegate methods will fire.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be helpful but this is what I do in my situation.

I have a tableview for an venue/business with 7 table cells. One of the table cells contains a map with pindrop. When the user views an establishment for the very first time, i run a quick conditional to see if the mapview has been cached (or rather, saved as image). if the image does not exist, i load a fresh mapview into the cell and add a single pindrop annotation. After both the mapview has loaded and the annotation has dropped, i save the view layer to image, then remove the mapview (and release it since we needed to keep the delegate alive) from the cell and replace with the fresh new image. I suggest spawing a background thread to save the image/insert into cell. This way the table view doesn't choke up.

And then finally, the next time the user returns to that same venue/business, the mapview image exists and i load the image.

I know it's important for the map to fully load, otherwise your image saves with gray where the map did not load. if you're dropping a pin drop, you need to make sure your image saving method fires after both the map finished loading (mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:) and your annotation has dropped (mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:). Only after both have finished should you fire method to save image. i suggest using a delayed selector. I delay it by 1 second.

This same concept can surely be applied to other situations. Bottom line is, as strings42 states, you're going to have to add a visible mapview to your view in order to capture an image.

Comment: The delay was the missing piece. Even after the didFinishLoadingMap method gets called, I was still seeing a gray image until I added the delay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method below will always be called as the delegate of mapView,

```
mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:fullyRendered:
```

so, you can get map image from mapView here

```
- (UIImage *)renderToImage:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.bounds.size);
  [mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return image;
}
```